# jquery function parameters, objects and variables

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The snippet below is a function from a larger library that I was given by another co-worker. This function is called from another method in the prototype.  The `results` parameter is a string of XML that looks something like this:

```
<spellResult .....>
    <c o=0 l=1 s=1>string string string />
    <c o=10 l=1 s=1>string string string />
</spellResult>
```

```
parseResults: function(results) {
    var self = this;
    this.results = [];
    var spellcheckFound = $(results).find('c');
    $(results).find('c').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            offset = $this.attr('o'),
            length = $this.attr('l');
        self.results.push({
            word: self.text.substr(offset, length),
            suggestions: $this.text().split(/\s/)
        });
    });
    this.displayResults();
},
```

So:

1. How does the `results` parameter differ from `this.results`?
2. Isn't the line `this.results = [];` clearing out the results parameter?
3. Is `self.results` a different object/variable or is it a reference to one of the others?
4. One more newbie question - what is `$(results)` in all of this?

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a bunch of `console.log()`s all over the place to see how each of the objects change. For instance after `this.results = [];` add `console.log(self.results)` to see if it is empty.

Comment: self is a reserved word. Bad, bad, bad estump. Bad. edit: ok maybe not reserved, but easily confused with window.self

Comment: `<c o=0 l=1 s=1>string string string />` is definitely not correct XML, but I guess you did not post it correctly. Before you post, you  should make sure that your code is free from obvious syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

What is this for:

```
 var self = this;
 this.results = [];
```

With `this.results = [];` you empty the `array`.

It is a little too little information to provide a proper answer, as we don't know what `results` is exactly?

As jasper says, do some proper debugging with `console.log` i.e. `console.log(typeof results)` and `console.log(results)` to see what's coming in.

"One more newbie question - what is $(results) in all of this?"

`$(results)` is the object of `results`. Basically what `$(results).find('c').each(function() {` does is find the elements `c` in `results` and loops through them.

Answer (score 0):

> how does the 'results' parameter differ from 'this.results'?

`this.results` refers to a property named results on `this`.  The meaning of `this` depends on how the function was called.  `results` is the XML that is being processed.  It is bad naming to call it `results`; a better name would be `resultsXML`.

> isn't the line 'this.results = [];' clearing out the results parameter?

Yes; the code is processing the XML, replacing `this.results` with the results of the processing.

> is 'self.results' a different object/variable or is it a reference to one of the others?

Since `self` is assigned to `this`, `self.results` would reference the same object as `this.results`.  Using a `self` variable is a common technique to capture a value of `this` within code.  Since the call to `each` establishes a new meaning for `this` -- the XML element being processed -- that's why `self` was initialized to `this` before the call to `each`.

> and one more newbie question - what is $(results) in all of this?

That is creating a jQuery object wrapper around the XML, allowing the code to use jQuery-style navigation within the XML.

Comment: *"...or the function itself"*: That is very unlikely. `this` is determined based on how the function is called. If it is called as standalone function, `this` normally refers to the global object. For `this` to refer to the function itself, one would have to call `func.call(func)`, which is quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How does the results parameter differ from this.results?

results is a local variable passed to the function. this.results is a property on the object called "this", which is the function itself (everything in javascript is an object, including functions)

> 2. Isn't the line this.results = []; clearing out the results parameter?

this.results = []; is shorthand for declaring a new empty array object. notice you do not need to use "var" keyword when declaring a new property on an object - it just creates it automagically or overwrites a previous property if the names collide.

> 3. Is self.results a different object/variable or is it a reference to one of the others?

since self and this are a reference to the same object, this.results and self.results are the same property. otherwise you would be getting an "object expected" error when you say self.results.push(...)

> 4. One more newbie question - what is $(results) in all of this?

$(results) is taking your javascript object called results and wrapping it in a jquery object, which allows you to access jquery prototype functions such as .find() and .each()

On a side note - please rewrite the code you posted. My eyes hurt. Especially the part where you do all the processing to initialize the spellcheckFound variable and then do all that processing again on the next line instead of just using spellcheckFound :P